# Possible to have selenium do its tests closed using Guard in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, guard

I am currently using the `guard-cucumber` gem so it is running cucumber tests constantly in the background while I am developing in Ruby on Rails.  Some of those tests are `cucumber` tests that open up a browser to run selenium tests.  Is it possible to have these tests done closed but still with selenium?

```
rails 3.0.3
guard 1.0.2
guard-cucumber 0.7.5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible with the Selenium driver. From their README:

> At the moment, Capybara supports Selenium 2.0 (Webdriver), not
>   Selenium RC. **Provided Firefox is installed**, everything is set up
>   for you, and you should be able to start using Selenium right away.

You should really try capybara-webkit (https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit):

> The capybara-webkit driver is for true headless testing. It uses
>   QtWebKit to start a rendering engine process. It can execute
>   JavaScript as well. It is significantly faster than drivers like
>   Selenium since it does not load an entire browser.

It's all running in the terminal which is super awesome.